# Python - Relational operators in lists

Tags: python, list, min

I have a list and wish to output items according to relational operations.

`a = range(10)`.
I wish to do :
`min(a[a>5])` -> `6`

**How do I accomplish this ?**

I have `print min([x for x in a if x > 5])` but is there something better ?

The output of `a[a>5]` is `1`.

**What does it mean ?**

I initially thought it is returning `1` to show that this condition is satisfied by the members of list. However, `a[a>50]` also returns `1`.

Comment: `a[a>5] == a[True] == a[1] == 1`. In Python 3 you'll get `TypeError` for this.

Comment: You can use that syntax if you use `numpy`, otherwise your current approach is fine - you could go `min(filter(lambda x: x > 5, range(10)))` for a more functional approach, but generator expressions/list comprehensions are generally considered more pythonic

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary
I am not sure I understand relational operations on lists.
`>>> a = range(10); >>> print type(a), a > 15` gives `<type 'list'> True`

What is happening ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary In Python 2(CPython 2) the objects of different types are  compared using their type names, so `'list'` > `'integer'`. In Python 3 this has been fixed and comparing different objects with no ordering possible will raise TypeError. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Answer (score 5):

You could use a generator expression to perform the filtering first

```
>>> min(i for i in a if i > 5)
6
```

This avoids having to create a list in memory if you had `min` evaluate the result of a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a library to do what you want, you can use `numpy` . It allows that kind of [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). Example -

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [6]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

In [8]: na = np.array(a) #There are better ways to create this numpy array, like `np.arange(1,13)`

In [9]: na[na > 5]
Out[9]: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

In [10]: min(na[na > 5])
Out[10]: 6
```

Comment: `na = np.arange(1, 13)` would save a few lines!

Comment: yes, But I just put in that to show how to convert a normal list to numpy array , though its trivial :-)